Socle of the maximal ideal and its square for a local ring with nonzero square of maximal ideal
Let $(R, \mathfrak m, k)$ be a Noetherian local ring such that $\mathfrak m^2\neq 0$. If $\text{Hom}_R(k, \mathfrak m^2)=0$, then is it true that $\text{Hom}_R(k, \mathfrak m)=0$?
My thoughts: Since $R$ is not a field, $\text{Hom}_R(k, \mathfrak m)=\text{Hom}_R(k, R)$. Apart from this, I have no idea what could be useful...please help

Given an homomorphism $k\rightarrow \mathfrak{m}$, try to compose it with the canonical $\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow\mathfrak{m}^2.$

@Somerandommathematician: what canonical morphism $\mathfrak m \to \mathfrak m^2$ are you talking about? I'm not aware of any...

Sorry, a bit of dyslexia there. I missread the hypothesis, the canonical map is of course from $\mathfrak{m}^2$ to $\mathfrak{m}$.

I don't understand the claim in the 2nd paragraph.

@MartinBrandenburg: you mean like the validity of $\text{Hom}_R(k, \mathfrak m)=\text{Hom}_R(k, R)$ when $R$ is not a field ?

Try. $R=k[[x,y]]/(x^2,xy)$.

@Mohan: thanks ... if you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Just an expansion of my comment.
Take $R=k[[x,y]]/(x^2,xy)$. Then, the socle is one dimensional, generated by $x$ which is in the maximal ideal, but not in its square. Of course, the square of the maximal ideal is the principal ideal generated by $y^2$ and nonzero.
